# BeautifulSoup4 scraping cannot reach beyond the first page in a website (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape from the first page to page 14 of this website: https://cross-currents.berkeley.edu/archives?author=&title=&type=All&issue=All&region=All
Here is my code:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas 

#make a list of all web pages' urls
webpages=[]
for i in range(15):
    root_url = 'https://cross-currents.berkeley.edu/archives?author=&title=&type=All&issue=All&region=All&page='+ str(i)
    webpages.append(root_url)
    print(webpages)

#start looping through all pages
for item in webpages:  
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    data = r.get(item, headers=headers)
    page_soup = soup(data.text, 'html.parser')

#find targeted info and put them into a list to be exported to a csv file via pandas
    title_list = [title.text for title in page_soup.find_all('div', {'class':'field field-name-node-title'})]
    title = [el.replace('\n', '') for el in title_list]

#export to csv file via pandas
    dataset = {'Title': title}
    df = pandas.DataFrame(dataset)
    df.index.name = 'ArticleID'
    df.to_csv('example31.csv',encoding="utf-8")
```

The output csv file only contains targeted info of the last page. When I print "webpages", it shows that all the pages' urls have been properly put into the list. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply overwriting the same output CSV file for all the pages, you can call `.to_csv()` in the "append" mode to have the new data added to the end of the existing file:

```
df.to_csv('example31.csv', mode='a', encoding="utf-8", header=False)
```

Or, even better would be to collect the titles into a list of titles and then dump into a CSV once:

```
#start looping through all pages
titles = []
for item in webpages:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    data = r.get(item, headers=headers)
    page_soup = soup(data.text, 'html.parser')

    #find targeted info and put them into a list to be exported to a csv file via pandas
    title_list = [title.text for title in page_soup.find_all('div', {'class':'field field-name-node-title'})]

    titles += [el.replace('\n', '') for el in title_list]

# export to csv file via pandas
dataset = [{'Title': title} for title in titles]
df = pandas.DataFrame(dataset)
df.index.name = 'ArticleID'
df.to_csv('example31.csv', encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: thanks very much!! your first suggestion didn't work (still same result), but the "collect the titles into a list of titles and then dump into a CSV once" worked beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

Another way in addition to what alexce posted would be to keep appending the dataframe inside to a new dataframe and then write that to the CSV.

Declare finalDf as a dataframe outside the loops:

```
finalDf = pandas.DataFrame()
```

Later do this:

```
for item in webpages:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    data = r.get(item, headers=headers)
    page_soup = soup(data.text, 'html.parser')

#find targeted info and put them into lists to be exported to a csv file   via pandas
    title_list = [title.text for title in page_soup.find_all('div', {'class':'field field-name-node-title'})]
    title = [el.replace('\n', '') for el in title_list]

#export to csv file via pandas
    dataset = {'Title': title}
    df = pandas.DataFrame(dataset)
    finalDf = finalDf.append(df)
    #df.index.name = 'ArticleID'
    #df.to_csv('example31.csv', mode='a', encoding="utf-8", header=False)

finalDf = finalDf.reset_index(drop = True)
finalDf.index.name = 'ArticleID'
finalDf.to_csv('example31.csv', encoding="utf-8")
```

Notice the lines with `finalDf`

Comment: thanks for the input! This worked except the index number kept returning to 0 after 19 (instead of 0-400, it's 0-19 then 0-19 again and again). Any idea why that's the case?

Comment: @AshleyLiu I have updated the answer by adding reset_index(), you will now have 0-400 :)